# What is on copper supply line behind shutoff valve?

Tags: plumbing

I'm planning to replace soldered/sweat shutoff valves (which are stuck and not working) with push fittings. Already done under bath sink with the help of heat gun.

I noticed something attached to the copper supply lines (feeding cold water to the faucet) with orange tube hanging (behind shutoff valves). I want to know what is that? Please see pictures [[image: view pics][1]].

And is it safe to use heat gun/unsolder the shutoff valve with that thing behind?

Comment: Looks like you existing valves are standard multi-turn shutoff valves. If the symptoms are that you turn them to off but they don't fully stop water flow, the rubber gaskets inside are likely damaged/decomposed. The good news is that if you don't want replace them, you can fix them in place using a multi turn stop rebuild kit. It usually has a new shaft and washers/bushings. There are plenty of YouTube videos on how to rebuild one of these valves, like this one: https://www.thisoldhouse.com/plumbing/21016188/how-to-rebuild-a-shutoff-valve

Comment: Personally, I'd be opening up the wall and cutting the pipe before it's pierced by that saddle valve. If you have to (for depth purposes) extend the pipe, you can use a sharkbite coupler, but be sure to anchor the pipe stub well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a saddle fitting, that pierces the copper pipe and supplies water to another device.

Most of the time it's to the ice maker/ water line to the refrigerator, but could go to something else.

If you want to remove the shutoff with heat, but don't want to remove the saddle, wrap a wet(but not dripping) towel around the pipe between the shutoff and the saddle.

wrap another wet towel around the saddle.

Those towels will soak up the heat before too much get to the saddle and its fittings.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a drain valve to drain water from the pipe.  Might help to remove water in pipe for soldering/unsoldering.

It might also be an extra line to connect to another faucet/tap, like a spray hose.

It should be as safe as soldering on a new valve.